# plotting two xml file entries for comparison using python

Tags: python, xml, matplotlib, comparison

How to compare visually the entries of two xml files by plot them on dotted line chart.

the format of each xml file as follow:

```
<queue-export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/queue_file.xsd">
<data timestep="0.00">
    <lanes>
        <lane id="22972473#3_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="5.00"/>
    </lanes>
</data>
<data timestep="60.00">
    <lanes>
        <lane id="-22972470#0_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="5.00"/>
        <lane id="-22972470#2_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="6.01"/>
        <lane id="-4588224_0" queueing_time="60.00" queueing_length="97.32" queueing_length_experimental="0.00"/>
        <lane id="191556835#0_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="19.14"/>
        <lane id="191556835#1_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="14.36"/>
        <lane id="22972473#3_0" queueing_time="60.00" queueing_length="5.00" queueing_length_experimental="5.00"/>
        <lane id="47707171#1_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="11.08"/>
        <lane id="47707171#2_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="6.81"/>
    </lanes>
</data>
<data timestep="120.00">
    <lanes>
        <lane id="-168935757#0_0" queueing_time="60.00" queueing_length="85.84" queueing_length_experimental="0.00"/>
        <lane id="-4588219#3_0" queueing_time="60.00" queueing_length="120.82" queueing_length_experimental="0.00"/>
        <lane id="168935756_0" queueing_time="60.00" queueing_length="95.79" queueing_length_experimental="0.00"/>
        <lane id="196850607#1_0" queueing_time="60.00" queueing_length="108.43" queueing_length_experimental="0.00"/>
        <lane id="199847247#0_0" queueing_time="60.00" queueing_length="14.75" queueing_length_experimental="14.75"/>
    </lanes>
</data>
<data timestep="180.00">
    <lanes>
        <lane id=":25663154_5_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="8.04"/>
        <lane id=":3922684843_0_0" queueing_time="0.00" queueing_length="0.00" queueing_length_experimental="6.81"/>
    </lanes>
</data>
```

I want to visualize the difference in queuing-time or queuing-length in each xml file gradually for each data timestep.

Hope you can guide me to python code or library to use or approach to do.

Comment: Are you trying to aggregate the `queueing_time` and `queueing_length` for all `lanes` per `timestep`? So for `timestep=120`, are you wanting `queueing_time=300.00` and `queueing_length=425.63`?

Comment: yes, this seems reasonable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `lxml` library to get the values you want:

```
from lxml import etree

file1 = etree.parse('/path/to/file1.xml')

# This will give you a list of Elements
data1 = file1.xpath('//data')

agg_1 = []

for timestep in data1:
    ts = []

    # The lanes element is the only (immediate) child of data,
    # so we can get each lane as the children of lanes
    lanes = timestep.getchildren()[0].getchildren()

    # Need to get the queueing_time and queueing_length
    # attributes from each lane
    for lane in lanes:
        ts.append((lane.attrib.get('queueing_time'), lane.attrib.get('queueing_length'))

    x, y = sum([float(x) for x,_ in ts]), sum([float(y) for _,y in ts])
    agg_1.append((x,y))
```

That should give you a list structured like `[(0.00, 0.00), (120.00, 102.32),...]` where each entry represents a timestamp (assuming all of them are there. You could repeat that process for `file_2` and that would give you the aggregated statistics. I haven't used `matplotlib` in some time, so I can add that into an edit, but that should get you started

NOTE: This does not handle the cases where:

- There are 0 `lane` elements in `lanes`
- A timestep value isn't in the
  xml (so if 60 was skipped, for instance)